# Aggregating information from different tables having 1-n relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, join, vb6

I have a query in which I need to get aggregated information (Sum of different fields) to prepare a report. The query looks like below.

```
SELECT a.pipe_sys,
       d.type_desc,
       e.rt,
       COUNT(a.weld_no) totaljoints,
       SUM(a.w_c) welded,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.is_qualifying_weld = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) qualifyingwelds,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.has_penalties = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) penalties,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.r_c = 1 AND c.is_qualifying_weld = 0 AND a.has_penalties = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tested,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.rt_res = 'ACC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) accepted
FROM   xl_weld_master a,
       imac_ndt       b,
       welder_list    c
WHERE  a.spool_no = c.spool_no
AND    a.cs_no = c.cs_no
AND    a.weld_no = c.weld_no
AND    a.spool_no = b.spool_no
AND    a.cs_no = b.cs_no
AND    a.weld_no = b.weld_no
GROUP  BY a.pipe_sys,
          d.type_desc,
          e.rt;
```

Table a and b have 1-1 relationship which means 1 weld has one NDT (test) information. While table a and c has 1-n relationship which means a weld can be welded by multiple welders (normally 3-4 welders).

Now when I run the above query, because table A-C has 1-n relationship so duplicate records are returned per weld and that makes the aggregates incorrect.

For example 1 weld is welded by 3 welders, so i will get welded Count as 3 instead of 1 and same for all others. How can I correct this?

P.S: this is a very old VB6 application with very poorly written code, so excuse me for this.

Comment: Please update your question to add sample data from your tables along with the expected output of your query based on that data.

Comment: and if you use `count(distinct a.WELD_NO)`?

Comment: also, you have `d.type_desc` in your query, but no table in the from clause that's aliased to `d`. The same for `e.rt`. Were they typos?

Comment: You can join & aggregate separately then join the aggregtions into one table. This is a faq.